# Get NUnit Project Name with a dll

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a test solution that has multiple NUnit Projects that refer a dll having logging capabilities.

During the [OneTimeSetUp] (for every NUnit project) I am creating a log file for the currently executing project (the method for which is within the dll). I would like to retrieve the NUnit project name within the dll so that I can use it for naming the log file. I can pass the information from the NUnit project to the dll but can I somehow retrieve it within the dll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to directly access the NUnit project name through which the assembly was invoked.

However, the script that runs nunit knows the name of the project,so you can simply pass it as a test run parameter using nunit3-console. Use the `--params` option on the command line.

To retrieve the name from your test code, use `TestContext`.

Comment: Thank you, will pass it from the NUnit Project

Comment: @Charlie is there still no mechanism that allows us to get the name of a dll containing the currently executed tests? Especially when executed from the VS test adapter, it is not a sufficient solution.

Comment: Your question asked about the "NUnit project name" so that's  what I answered. If you update the question, I'll update the answer. But in updating please be clear about where the code that needs to get this is located. Both @Sean and I assumed it was in your test code, since you said it was part of the assembly level OneTimeSetUp. But in another comment you say it's in a logging assembly. Sorry, but we have to have the facts first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the project that is currently executing you can use

```cs
GetType().Assembly.ManifestModule.Name
```

in your setup, which will return the name of the dll that is executing

Comment: He asked about the NUnit project name, not the assembly. NUnit projects are files with type `.nunit`.

Comment: As I have a similar situation and tested it: Your solution will show a DLL, but it's the DLL that is dealing with the logging (e.g. MyLoggingPlugin.dll). It does however not name the DLL containing the tests that get executed.